# Battery simulator

Tags: battery-charging, lithium

I wanted to make battery simulator, used to test li ion charger, and i have the schematic of the one that i use at work. I turn the knob and adjust the voltage at P1 and i can measure sink current at P2.
But i am not able to understand the working of this ckt. I can read voltage at P1 even though there's no voltage source attached at the emitter of transistor.
[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Want to know working of this ckt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This "battery simulator" is only intended to simulate a battery for the purpose of charging.

If it was as drawn it would act like an ideal diode connected to a stiff voltage source (adjustable, they say, from 1V to 8.8V, I didn't work it out), through a 250m\$\Omega\$ resistor.

You ask where is the voltage with the output 'open' coming from? Well that's hard to see because the schematic symbol of the [TIP127](http://C:%5CDocuments%20and%20Settings%5CSpehro%20Pefhany%5CDesktop%5C2015-06-01%2015_01_36-TIP125.pdf%20(SECURED)%20-%20Adobe%20Acrobat%20Professional.png) is incomplete. See below:

[image]

Now it should be obvious that the voltage is coming from the output of the op-amp, through R1 and R2 in series (8.12K). Also it should be obvious that it won't work that way if the MOSFET shown is used, unless you connect a resistor from gate to source.

Answer (score 1):

There's a potentiometer that defines a trip point. When the voltage applied (BAT+) is deemed to exceed that trip point, Q1 turns on and current is taken through Q1 and dumped into R2 thru R6. The LM358 makes the judgement call on whether the voltage is above or below the trip point. It's a comparator and either drives Q1 into the on state or turns Q1 off.

Comment: No, it doesn't just trip at some voltage. Let me tell you the operation. I connected my voltmeter at p1 and when i turn the knob i measure voltage from 1 to 8.8 V at P1. So where is this voltage coming from my opamp is driving base of q1 and you can see there's no voltage source connected to collector or emitter of q1.

Comment: Look at the internal circuit of the TIP127 and you'll see that there are resistors across the Base-Emitter junction of the two transistors (~8k ohm).  Any voltage at the base of the TP127 from U2A will appear at P1 if it is open, attenuated by R11+R7 (~40/48) to abut 80% of the voltage from U2A.  kevin